# Como usar variable global en livewire

Tags: laravel, livewire

Estoy con un inconveniente con livewire.
Creé una variable global pero cuando quiero acceder desde una vista en livewire me dice que no está declarada.

Lo que hice fue crear dentro del controller general la variable

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use App\Models\Suscriber;
use View;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $shop;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        // Fetch the Site Settings object
        $this -> shop = Suscriber::where('slug', config('shop.SHOP_SLUG')) -> first();
        View::share('SHOP', $this -> shop);
    }
}
```

De esta manera accedo a la variable en las vistas y controladores sin problema.
Pero cuando accedo a una vista desde livewire obviamente no la toma porque no usa controllers.

Entonces lo que quisiera es hacer algo similar para poder acceder a la variable "SHOP" desde cualquier vista o componente de livewire.

Agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: Buen día, quiero ver si entendí bien, ¿Deseas utilizar `$shop` que actualmente está en un controlador, en un componente livewire?

Comment: Algo así...en realidad sé que no puedo xq la estoy declarando en Controller.php...entonces lo que quiero es saber la forma de crearla para usarla en los componentes de livewire, pero de manera global, que no tenga q declararla cada vez q creo un nuevo componente.

Comment: Podrías utilizar [`traits`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/traits), tanto laravel como livewire las soportan y es una buena forma de reutilizar código, no solamente variables sino también funciones

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Ok! voy a investigar cómo funciona. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me parece que lo que puedes hacer es usar el método mount() en un controlador Livewire y desde ahí pasarla a una vista.